# expo delete permission location

Tags: android, typescript, permissions, expo

I try to post my app on google play store, but they say I can't because I use location, but I never use it..

If I make an app-bundle and I open it with Android Studio, I find this on Manifest :

```java
[...]
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
[...]
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
[...]
```

How I'm suppose to delete it? and how to know where this is use ?

My package.json :

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.2",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~8.2.1",
    "firebase": "7.9.0",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-barcode-builder": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.41",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.62.13",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  },
```

Comment: see the docs: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#permissions-on-android

note that permissions were revamped in sdk 39 and you may want to update to it in order to have better control over permissions included in your app. https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-decrease-permission-on-android/43525/6?u=notbrent

Comment: i found this http://derinkod.com/expo-background-location-permission-removal/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ran into the same problem and the Play Store changed their policy on location permissions effective Mar 29, 2021. Here's what I've found:

**1. For managed Expo:**

Modify app.json to add "permissions" and specify only those that you want. This will override Expo's default set of permissions. An empty array is fine if you require no permissions.

```
android: {
    permissions: ["READ_CONTACTS", "WRITE_SETTINGS"]
    ...
```

Ref: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions

Note that Expo includes some manufacturer permissions by default. You may want to add these in:

```
"com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE",
"com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT",
"com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE",
"com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES",
"com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE",
"com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS",
"com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT",
"com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ",
"com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE"
```

**2. For bare Expo:**

Remove specific permissions by using *tools:node="remove"* in your AndroidManifest.xml

Ref: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#excluding-android-permissions-in-bare-workflow

**3. expo-location**

If you have expo-location installed, it will automatically request ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION (seems like ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION as well). I had expo-location installed at one point, and had to remove it from node_modules and package-lock.json manually.

Ref: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/permissions/#permissions-on-android

Comment: It looks as though expo v40.0.1 requires expo-location as a sub module. Is this what you manually removed from package-lock.json and node_modules? That is going to cause build issues I believe since expo requires the package.

Answer (score 2):

*Add in file* **app.json** an empty array for permissions:

```
"android": {
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
      "package": "",
      "permissions": [],
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have fine grain control over the permissions, use expo config plugins.

1. Add a new file in project root withAndroidRemovedPermissions.js:

```
  const {
  AndroidConfig,
  createRunOncePlugin,
  withAndroidManifest,
} = require('@expo/config-plugins');

const withAndroidRemovedPermissions = (config, permissionsToBeRemoved) => {
  return withAndroidManifest(config, (config) => {
    AndroidConfig.Permissions.removePermissions(config.modResults, permissions);

    const usesPermissions = config.modResults.manifest['uses-permission'] || [];

    permissions.forEach((permission) => {
      permissionsToBeRemoved.push({
        $: {
          'tools:node': 'remove',
          'android:name': permission,
        },
      });
    });

    config.modResults.manifest['uses-permission'] = usesPermissions;
    config.modResults.manifest.$['xmlns:tools'] =
      'http://schemas.android.com/tools';

    return config;
  });
};

module.exports = createRunOncePlugin(
  withAndroidRemovedPermissions,
  'withAndroidRemovedPermissions'
);
```

then in your app.json file

```
    {
  "plugins": [
     [
        "./withAndroidRemovedPermissions",
        [
          "android.permission.WHATEVER_PERMISSION_YOU_NEED_1",
          "android.permission.WHATEVER_PERMISSION_YO_NEED_2"
        ]
      ],
   ],
}
```

Comment: Source: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3021